# Azure: "Disallowed by policy" error trying to capture a VM

Tags: azure, sysprep

I'm working through some guided labs studying for the AZ-900 Azure Fundamentals certification test.

The labs instructed me to:

1. Create an ARM VM with Visual Studio (OK)
2. Run SysPrep on the VM
3. "Capture" the SysPrep'ed VM in order to create a template image

I'm stuck on Step 3:

- The lab instructed us to create a B2ms image.
- Azure "Capture" menus require a "Gallery".
- But "Capture > Review + Create" fails:

  ```
      ERROR: Disallowed by policy
      Policy: Lockdown_AKS_VM_SKY_Standard_B2ms
  ```

Q: What's going on?

Q: How can I work around it?

Comment: Is this using your own subscription, or a lab sub provided by MS?

Comment: Good question: the subscription, resource group, etc. are from the lab provider.  That's one of the reasons I'm using the labs - so I don't risk running up $$$ charges on my own subscription.  It's also why I chose size "B2ms" - because the lab told me to.  And yes, I've tried asking the lab directly - no go, so far :(

Comment: So this is really down to the lab provider, there is an Azure policy stopping what you are doing, but this is a custom policy created by the provider, not a built in one, so I can't tell you what it is blocking

Comment: Thank you - that helps.  I assumed that "Lockdown_AKS_VM_SKY_Standard_B2ms" was a *Microsoft* policy, not a custom policy.